# Easier way to do checkouts in git than to have to type the full commit's hash id

Tags: git, version-control

I am currently checking out other commits by using a commit's full hash id:

```
git checkout b56da2b535106d6df6d7caebfd455dd65b70eaf6
```

but this is a bit boring. Isn't there another way to do it? Maybe only typing the first letters of the hash or something? I have the idea of having read something alone those lines but I am not too sure about it.

Thanks

Ed[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use any unambiguous prefix of the hash. Also, if you are trying to go through the history by a certain scheme, things like `HEAD^^^` (i.e. the great grandparent of the current HEAD) work. See [`git help revisions`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for more ways to specify this.

But I usually simply use copy+paste from gitk.

Comment: I've tried the prefix but it didn't seem to work. Maybe it has some lower bound? At least git checkout b5 (for the above case) doesn't seem work, nor b5.. nor b56....

Comment: IIRC you need at least four characters. So b56d should work. Unless there is another commit (or other object) that also starts with b56d (this gets more likely as you have more commits, obviously). Six characters is almost guaranteed to be enough.

Comment: @devoured: Once a repository's got a good amount of history and content, there's a pretty good chance of collision in the first two characters, and sometimes the first three, so starting with four is a pretty good habit. Also, I commonly select and middle-click paste (on linux) from git log output.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I normally do when I need to get the full sha1 of anything on the commandline:

1. Copy the sha1 to the clipboard by double clicking it in xterm or gnome-terminal.
2. Get the sha1 to be pasted on the command line either by middle-clicking on the terminal window, or through a program, like so:

   $ git checkout `p`

Where "p" is a shell script I have:

```
$ cat ~/bin/p
xcopy -r 2>/dev/null
```

You can get xcopy from Simon Tatham (of putty fame) [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/utils/).

I used to use [xclip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/) to do the pasting, but I stopped using it for some reason I could not remember.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bazillion different ways to specify commits listed in the "SPECIFYING REVISIONS" section of [git-rev-parse](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html), including some interesting ones like `:/message` that uses the commit message.